# Where is the fuse box on a TGB Urban 125cc scooter?

Tags: scooter, fuse-panel

I can't find the fuse box on a TGB Urban 125cc scooter. I looked under the seat and under the foot rest. All i could find is the main fuse wired in the battery cable:

[image: tgb urban main fuse]

Is this the only fuse? Is there a fuse box with more? Where is it located?

Comment: Good questions show signs that you have researched or attempted to solve the problem first. Where have you looked for the fuse box? Have you searched the forums and come up empty? Could you link any sites you attempted to search for the fuse box location?

Comment: The idea of closing this question doesn't work.  It's simple but it's clear.  There are two answers for it.  I know @joernano can do research.  Please don't close this question.  It has answers.  I really don't see how much more can be added to make it clear.  "Where is the fusebox?" is pretty clear.  **do not close this question please**

Comment: @MooseLucifer You are right I was lazy on this one. Edited.

Comment: @DucatiKiller I should have waited a while to cast the close vote after posting my comment, but dammit if my little fingers got antsy. Sorry OP, and thank you for the edit.

Comment: I hope you haven't switched to scooters from your Ducati.

Comment: Oh yeah, AND....that single fuse right there is more than likely the only fuse on the scooter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I can't find the fuse location for the 125cc**

but....

The loation of the fuse on the 49cc version is in the battery compartment.

From the manual

> ### BATTERY AND FUSE.
>
> 1. THE BATTERY HAVE TWO TYPE ：REFILL WATER TYPE AND SEALED TYPE.
> 2. REPLACE THE BATTERY, PLEASE TAKE OFF LEG SHIELD CUSHION, UNSCREW THE TAPPING SCREW AND REMOVE THE BATTERY BOX LID, YOU CAN TAKE OFF THE BATTERY AND CABLE.
>      SEALED TYPE REQUIRING NO MAINTENANCE OF FLUID LEVER, DO NOT REMOVE SEALING CAPS.
> 3. THE FUSE IS NEAR THE BATTERY, ITS FUNCTIONS IS TO PROTECT THE ELECTRIC PARTS AND AVOID DAMAGES CAUSED BY SHORT-CIRCUIT OR POWER OVER-LOAD, IF THE FUSE MELTS OFTEN, THEN THERE MAY BE SOME THING WRONG IN THE ELECTRIC WIRES OR THE ELECTRIC PARTS DO NOT WORK CORRECTLY. PLEASE GO TO AN AUTHORIZED DEALER TO EXAMINE IT IMMEDIATELY.
> 4. IF REPLACING THE FUSE, PLEASE ALWAYS USE A 7A TYPE.

[**Here is a link to a manual for the 125cc version.**](http://www.tgb-france.com/common/upload_fichier/servicemanual125250xmotion.pdf)  This manual is a over 200 pages but leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try looking in the battery compartment area? Sometimes those fuses will be directly wired into the positive battery cable (those smaller scooters typically have a single fuse I think, don't quote me though).